# How do I change my profile photo?

Tags: discussion, support, profile-picture

I am not able to change my profile photo. Why?

I signed up through my Google account and the default photo on my Google account was picked.

Comment: No i am not able to find profile option..After clicking on upper right photo,it navigates to my reputation

Comment: You have to click on the Profile tab at the top first. The most recent answer is from 2017; the dupe target probably needs a new answer to account for recent changes (or at least an edit to include that step).

Comment: First Click  on [Edit your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current) than click on [Change picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZusG3.png)